# How To Set SupportRTL in AndroidManifest for Specifed Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-manifest

i removed Action Bar from all activities Then I put to specific  activity an action bar and when i used SupportsRtl (in Specifed Activity) for change title position but title position still no changed

styles :

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="myTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.user.classmanager">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".FirstTab" />
    <activity android:name=".SecondTab" />
    <activity android:name=".ThirdTab" />

    <activity android:name=".AddNewClass"
        android:theme = "@style/myTheme"
        android:supportsRtl="true"  <==== DONT WORK
        android:label="اضافه کردن کلاس">
    </activity>
</application> </manifest>
```

Comment: in your `.AddNewClass` u get the title ?

Comment: What is your target `SDK`? `android:supportsRtl="true"` in `application` tag is only available from API 17 and above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do such thing in `Manifest.xml`.

I recommend set `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` into your activity parent layout to set just that specific activity support rtl.

[this article has great information about layout directions support.](https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2)

Comment: By setting `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` you do not *support* right-to-left layout direction but *force* it for all languages (LTR will no longer work).

Comment: Well yea but it works when all the page uses one RTL language.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question i tested >>android:layoutDirection="rtl"<< in xml target but still doesn't work but I found the problem , This code work for me : getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) @paulina_glab

Answer (score 2):

When you enable support for RTL layouts like this:

```
<application
    ...
    android:supportsRtl="true">
```

You enable the use of this feature for **every activity** in the app.

This suggests that the problem probably lies in the layout of your `AppBarLayout`/ `Toolbar`.

In order for the application to properly reflect the direction, you should use the appropriate attributes - instead of using `Left`/`Right`, you should use `Start`/`End` ones. To read more check [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html).

You can also use the automatic Android Studio option by selecting **Refactor** > **Add RTL Support Where Possible...**

[image]